# Payable contract Tron solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity, trx

I have read many example of solidity contract to pay and collect ether from users but I would like to know how this can be applied to TRX.
I mean how can I transfer TRX token from a msg.sender to the owner of the contract ?
And one more, ho can retrieve token from the contract?
Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems like TRX tokens have been swapped a while ago from Ethereum network to Tron Mainnet.

Comment: Yes, but just for try I’m doing some rest using Shasta network, but the problem is I don’t know how to say the contract to user TRX and how to perform payments

Comment: i figured out how to transfer the value from the sender to the owner, but i cant pay back in case i want to send money from the owner to the sender. If i send back msg.value the contract run well but when i pay back msg.value*2 for example i get "the contractor should be payable if i send value"...why ?